# is /etc/sudoers writable or not

Tags: linux, bash, unix, file-permissions, sudo

The default permission in /etc/sudoers file is readonly for root and group root as in picture is obvious :

[image]

So when you open it with any test editor it can't be written and give error read only.

now my question is that when i run a bash script that contains bellow code or copy paste it in terminal it will append to this file. how is that possible ??! file is does not have write permissions set so how this is hapenning ?

```
cat >> /etc/sudoers << EOF
%group1  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
EOF
```

Comment: You need to use visudo to edit it.  If you must use cat or sed, try using sudoedit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @d-chord ....

Comment: Using `sed` will work _if_ you're very careful. Look into `EDITOR=sed visudo ...` if you must.  Can you create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead to meet your need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root can ignore permissions.

Consider this example:

```
[/tmp/foo]$ echo "bar" > foo
[/tmp/foo]$ chmod 000 foo
[/tmp/foo]$ ls -l foo
---------- 1 vidarlo users 4 Sep 29 19:19 foo
[/tmp/foo]$ cat foo
cat: foo: Permission denied
[/tmp/foo]$ sudo cat foo
bar
[/tmp/foo]$
```

Normal user is denied; root is not denied, even though root does not have read permissions.

Comment: I get what you mean, my question is that why when i open sudoers file with vim even though im root it will give permission deny but i can edit same file  in bash ?

Comment: With `vi` I get `-- INSERT -- W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file` when attempting to insert as root. It however works fine.

Comment: You are write i did not pay too much attention to the message, after doing 'wq' in vi it gives error that '!' must be used to override read only ...
many thanks to your answer